# Ruby current class

Tags: ruby

How do I determine the current open class in Ruby?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Inside of a `class` definition body, `self` refers to the class itself. `Module#name` will tell you the name of the class/module, but only if it actually has one. (In Ruby, there is no such thing as a "class name". Classes are simply objects just like any other which get assigned to variables just like any other. It's just that if you happen to assign a class object to a constant, then the `name` method will return the name of that constant.)

Example:

```
puts class Foo
  name
end
# Foo
```

But:

```
bar = Class.new
bar.name # => nil
BAR = bar
bar.name #=> 'BAR'
```

Answer (score 32):

Inside the class itself:

```
class_name = self.class
```

On an initialized object named `obj`:

```
class_name = obj.class
```

Comment: You use 'class' as a variable and 'class' is a reserved keyword. Rename variable 'class'

Comment: `class_name` still isn't a great name for that variable, since it is the class object, not the name string. A better name for the variable might be `klass`.

Answer (score 3):

if you have `obj = SomeClass.new` you get the class with `obj.class`

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to compare via the class name (string):

```
class Foo
  def my_class_name_is
    self.class.name
  end
end

Foo.new.my_class_name_is
=> "Foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `name` method was overwrote, I find `to_s` give me this same result

```
class Foo
 puts self.name
 puts self.to_s
end
#=> Foo
#=> Foo
```